# RecyclerView - notifyDataSetChanged Only Works After 1 Millisecond Delay

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, layout-inflater, notifydatasetchanged

I am creating a custom keyboard app, which uses a `InputMethodService`.
I've noticed something very odd.

If I call `mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (`mainview.tabRecycler` is a recycler view, which I can reference like this due to Kotlin extensions) **inside of** the overrided `onCreateInputView` method then nothing happens.

Here is an example where nothing happens:

```
override fun onCreateInputView(): View {

    mainview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboardmain, null)

    //Insert code that manipulates the variable called tabs, which is just a List

    mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter = TabAdapter(tabs, this)

    mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    return mainview
}
```

However, if I call `mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from within a coroutine with a delay of at least 1 millisecond, then the `recyclerview` "tabRecyclerView" will show the views.

Here is an example:

```
override fun onCreateInputView(): View {

    mainview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboardmain, null)

    //Insert code that manipulates the variable called tabs, which is just a List

    mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter = TabAdapter(tabs, this)

launch(UI) {
           //The delay is important, it needs to be here
           delay(1)
            mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    return mainview
}
```

I suspect that               `mainview.tabRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will only refresh `tabRecyclerView` after the method `onCreateInputView` completes and returns the inflated `mainview` object.

Due to this odd behavior, I'm forced to create a coroutine with a delay of at least 1 millisecond, just so I can update the dataset for the adapter.

This doesn't seem like a good way to update my recyclerview's dataset?

What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Although my post uses examples in Kotlin, answers in Java are fine too.

Comment: @MarkKeen Since when inflate is asynchronous? The documentation says nothing about that. Can you provide any reference that shows share you are saying?

Comment: Removed comment, thanks @pskink for confirming that I was incorrect.

Comment: @pskink Setting the adapter and not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't do anything. I believe either [A] the adapter must be set after the `onCreateInputView` method has been finished or [B] if the adapter is set before `onCreateInputView` is finished, then `notifyDataSetChanged()` must be called after `onCreateInputView` is finished.

Comment: @pskink I know I can just call `setAdapter()`, but for some reason `setAdapter()` does not work if I call it while `onCreateInputView()` has not finished. I need to call `setAdapter()` once `onCreateInputView()` has finished running and returned the object `mainview`. Unfortunately, I can't call `setAdapter()` from within a coroutine, so I'm forced to call `setAdapter()` inside `onCreateInputView()` and use a coroutine to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` with a delay of 1 milliseconds, so I know that `onCreateInputView` has finished

Comment: @pskink It seems like `onStartInputView` is called after `onCreateInputView`. So, setting my adapters in that method could work. However, looking at the documentation for that method, it seems like that is not the proper place to set my adapters/use `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @pskink Apologies, the documentation also says "to deal with input starting within the input area of the IME." in reference to `onStartInputView`, which made me think that it was called if you had a search bar (or `EditText`) within a custom keyboard. Now I'm confused because the sentence I found from the documentation and the sentences you found within the documentation seem to contradict, even though they are from the same document located at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171842/discussion-between-roymunson-and-pskink).